# Is there an AS 3.0 play and die function?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip, removechild

Is there any function in AS 3.0 that plays a MovieClip and then does removeChild() after it has been played? I don´t want to stop() it i just want to remove the child from stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a code example, suggested by Sr.Richie, here is what is required:

Inside the MC to play and remove, add this frame code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function (e:Event):void {
   if(currentFrame==totalFrames) {
      removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arguments.callee);
      parent.removeChild(this);     
   }
}
```

Note I haven't tested this code, but it's the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no built-in method to do it.

But you can let your objects extend MovieClip, and create a custom method triggered by an ENTER_FRAME event to check if the last frame is reached, and remove them from the parent then

Comment: yeah thanks! i manage to make something like this for it to work, at this point i don't remember what my problem was, but again thanks a lot!